# Listen to android calendar changes. Problem on Android 12

Tags: android, android-studio, calendar, broadcastreceiver, android-appwidget

I use an intent filter to receive in the appwidget provider if calendar was changed and update the widget in case of changes...

**My code in Manifest:**

```
    <receiver android:name="my.package.name.WidgetProvider">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Then code in WidgetProvider:**

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

    if (intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED)) {
        val thisAppWidget = ComponentName(
            context.packageName, javaClass.name
        )
        val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
            .getInstance(context)
        val ids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget)
        // Update widgets
        for (appWidgetId in ids) {
                updateWidget(
                    context,
                    appWidgetManager,
                    appWidgetId
                )
        }
    }

    super.onReceive(context, intent)
```

}

On Nokia with Android 10 everything works fine: if calendar is changed the appwidget is updated. **But on OnePlus 8T with Android 12 appwidget doesn't update after changes in calendar.**

What's wrong with the code? What's been changed in Android 12? How to receive signal about calendar changes on all devices?

Can somebody help?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @Lior Iluz
Yes, I've solved the problem.
I use JobScheduler to listen to the changes in Calendar Provider.
Unfortunately, familiar intent filter for  action android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED desn't work on modern Android anymore.

Comment: thanks. I'm also using this solution and unfortunately, it seems it's getting killed by Doze when the app is in background. Can you share your JobService implementation?